# Convert JSON String to XML string

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, xml-serialization

I have a JSON string as :

```
var jsonString = JSON.stringify(dataObject);
document.getElementById("hdnChromedata").value = jsonString;
```

**==> hdnChromedata = JSON string**

BUT in a different code section I am storing XML serialized string to "hdnChromedata" .as :

```
XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(vinDescription.GetType());
StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter();

xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, vinDescription);
this.hdnChromedata.Value = textWriter.ToString();
```

**==> hdnChromedata = XML string**

AND while retriving the values I am deserializing the string like this :

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(this.hdnChromedata.Value);
XmlNodeReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(doc.DocumentElement);

XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(decodedInfo.GetType());
object textObj = ser.Deserialize(reader);
vinDescription = (AutoExact.AEVINDecoderService.VINDescription)textObj;
```

***HERE the line doc.LoadXml(this.hdnChromedata.Value)
is throwing error when hdnChromedata is a JSON string.***

My question is, HOW can I make this JSON String to XML string?

OR is there any other to address this?

**Basically I need a method to convert JSON string to XML string in ASP.NET 1.1**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Json.NET library's `JsonConvert` for that. See the specifics at http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/index.html?topic=html/ConvertingJSONandXML.htm.

Json.NET is an open-source JSON handling library for .NET, and it's the best there is.

Comment: Is it some kind of third party reference I will need to add? I afraid I can not reference it from my project..

Comment: Yes, you need to reference the DLL from your project.

Comment: Is not there any other way to convert JSON string to XML string..I dont think referencing a DLL from project is going to be feasible for me..

Comment: Are you saying you cannot use any libraries in your projects?? That would mean that you have to write every bit of functionality you might need yourself unless it happens to be in the System library...

Comment: Yes..my client does not agree for third paryy dlls

Comment: Then, if you don't mind my saying so, your client is a fool, and this makes your life much harder.

Comment: Your only option then is to write your own routines to convert the JSON to XML I suppose, or to find a way that makes such conversion unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

No need for conversion, just test the first character of the string before deserialising it. If the string starts with `<`, then treat it as XML, and if it starts with `{`, then treat it as JSON.

Comment: What if it starts with `' '`? :)

Comment: I guess this depends on the OP's requirements, however I like this approach

Comment: @L.B: `throw new InvalidOperationException` :-)

Comment: @ChristianHayter.. I have written a lot of code which uses the XML object...If I will follow the approach you suggested, I will have to write the same code again for JSON object too..

Comment: @Learner: You should not be writing two different kinds of data to the same variable in different places. If you choose to do that, you must accept the consequences. Pick one data format and stick with it.

Comment: @ChristianHayter The point is..I have this WCF service which sends me data...AS I am in ASP.NET 1.1 , in code behind I have to fetch it in XML and in jQuery ajax way I am getting it in JSON...HEnce the problem is coming..I hope this explains my situation

Comment: @Learner: I don't understand. Surely you just ask the service for the data in the format that you want?

Answer (score -1):

Use json-lib, a library which adds JSON support to any Java program. json-lib provides an XMLSerializer which can be used to output XML from a JSON object.

https://discursive.atlassian.net/wiki/display/CJCOOK/Converting+JSON+to+XML